# How to get memcache to work on php with Windows

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I am trying to get memcahe enabled on my Phpinfo().

Hi everyone, I am a newbie when its comes to working with memcache. So I have been trying to get memcache enabled on my php, but I have had very little luck.

According to my `phpinfo()` my php build version is API320190902,TS,VC15 and entails that I have to enable php_memcache.dll which is of the same VC (i.e VC15).

I have done that, by placing the php_memcache.dll file in my php/ext folder and enabling the extension in my php.ini by stating "extension=php_memcache.dll". But despite doing all this, I can't seem to get the memcache enabled, and my `phpinfo()` does not show the desired memcached section.

Additionally my Apache log states

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'php_memcache.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_memcache.dll (The
> specified module could not be found.)"

Can someone kindly help me figure out where I am missing it, or not doing right?

By the way, I tested this on Xampp and the .dll file was downloaded from the link https://github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll

Attached are screen shots of my Apache logs, php.ini, php/ext and `phpinfo()`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @nono303 any ideas of where I am getting it wrong

Comment: I have seen this error message on Windows when either the threading or bit-ness (32/64) isn’t matched

Comment: @sokoms93 Have you tried anything [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173231/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp-windows-7-8-10)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load MemcacheD extension in PHP 8.1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74626434/unable-to-load-memcached-extension-in-php-8-1-7)

Answer (score 1):

There are common things that are often encountered in PHP and Memcache(D) related issues:

1. Do you need the MEMCACHED or the MEMCACHE extension?
2. Is the MEMCACHED server already running? (in your case, that's not the problem yet)
3. Is the installed PHP extension x64 and Threadsafe compatible (as your system requires by looking at your phpinfo).

Personally, I use another PHP extension which works perfectly under PHP7 and PHP8:
**memcached 3.2.0 for Windows**
https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached/3.2.0/windows

Note: in addition to the usual DLL extension that you will copy to php/ext/ (and enable in your php.ini), you will also need to **copy libmemcached.dll and libhashkit.dll** to a directory belonging to your system path.

Comment: I added these files `copy libmemcached.dll and libhashkit.dll` to folder with my php.exe and everything works fine!
One more thing: also it's require to have and to run memcached.exe itself. It can be find on github https://github.com/jefyt/memcached-windows/releases/tag/1.6.8_mingw